# Running Local Script On SSH Server

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I'm using [`Linux`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) to log into a server using [`ssh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell). Once I'm logged in, I would like to execute a local [`Python`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)) script which uses [`netcat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) to run some program on the remote machine (it is therefore required to be logged in to access it).

Locally I can type `./script.py` on [`bash`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) to run the script however if I do it while being connected to the remote server that doesn't work. This is due to the fact that the terminal now is in a directory on the remote machine and no longer in a local one.

So how do I execute my local script against the remote machine while being logged in without copying it over first?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily using pipes:
my sample program to test: (py.py)

`import socket
print socket.gethostname()`

running remotely:

```
ssh remoteserver "python" < py.py
```

the output was:

```
remoteserver name
```

If your user's path not contains python, you must use full path

```
ssh remoteserver "/usr/bin/python" < py.py
```

in my environment.

Comment: Is this solution specific to python or possible to use this in other language as well (ofcourse in their syntax) ?

Comment: any program what can handle input redirection (pipes) can run by this method - I used perl, php, bash shell by this way before.

Comment: This is really awesome trick. I did not know about it earlier. Also my question was pretty lame. I did not think through before asking as i was admiring your solution. ;)